# SearchBoxScriptWebPart is not working properly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-box

I have created one custom WebPart and added `SearchBoxScriptWebPart` inside it.
Code block:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SearchWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

```
<div data-name="SearchBox" class="vde_SearchBox">
    <SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart ID="SearchBoxScriptWebPart" UseSiteCollectionSettings="false" 
        runat="server" Dir="LeftToRight" EmitStyleReference="False" ServerInitialRender="True" 
        ShowQuerySuggestions="False" TryInplaceQuery="False" UseSharedSettings="false" 
        ChromeType="None" __WebPartId="{E847430B-6408-464E-BFFC-6912EAB2493F}">           
    </SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart>
</div>
```

Using this my search user control is displayed but I'm not able to write anything inside it.

Is there any property missing?

Answer (score 0):

I do suggest to rewrite your control as follows:

```
<SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart ID="SearchBoxScriptWebPart" UseSiteCollectionSettings="true" 
        runat="server" Dir="LeftToRight" EmitStyleReference="False" ServerInitialRender="True" 
        ShowQuerySuggestions="true" TryInplaceQuery="False" UseSharedSettings="true"
        ResultsPageAddress="/searchcenter/Pages/results.aspx" 
        ChromeType="None" __WebPartId="{E847430B-6408-464E-BFFC-6912EAB2493F}">           
    </SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart>
```